# Simple Encryption not working

Tags: c++

I'm using a simple encryption that I found online. Basically, I'm streaming in a file, checking to see if that file is open (if not, display an error message) and putting each line in each element of the array while encrypting the information. Afterwards I stream that encrypted information onto an output file.

However, I'm getting nothing in my output.txt file. The encryption works fine if you test it by itself.

Here is my code:

```
#include <string>  
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream> // for ostringstream
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>

/* Credits to kylewbanks.com */
string encrypt (string content) {
    char key[3] = {'K'}; //Any chars will work
    string output = content;

    for (int i = 0; i < content.size(); i++)
        output[i] = content[i] ^ key[i % (sizeof(key) / sizeof(char))];

    return output;
}

int main() {
    string input, line;
    string content[10000];
    string encryptedContent[10000];

        int counter = 0, innerChoice = 0, i, finalCounter;

        cout << "\tPlease enter the file name to encrypt!\n";
        cout << "\tType '0' to get back to the menu!\n";
        cout << "Input >> ";

        cin >> input;

        /* Reads in the inputted file */
        ifstream file(input.c_str());
        //fopen, fscanf

        if(file.is_open()) {

            /* Counts number of lines in file */
            while (getline(file, line)) {
                counter++;
            }

            cout << counter;

            finalCounter = counter;

            for (i = 0; i < finalCounter; i++) {
                file >> content[i];
                encryptedContent[i] = encrypt(content[i]);
                cout << encryptedContent[i];
            }
        } else {
            cout << "\tUnable to open the file: " << input << "!\n";
        }

        /* Write encryption to file */
        ofstream outputFile("output.txt");
        for (i = 0; i < finalCounter ; i++) {
            outputFile << encryptedContent;
        }
        outputFile.close();
}
```

Any clue what is wrong?

Comment: Just a guess but have you tried flushing?

Comment: @JonnyHenly Fairly new to programming. What is flushing?

Comment: After reading all the lines in the file, your file pointer is at the end.  You need to do a `file.seekg(0);` to reset it back to the beginning.

Comment: I don't know the technical jargon, I usually think of it as *forcing the rest of the stream buffer to be written*, but here's a [`ostream::flush` C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/flush/) that may provide some insight. Flushing was just a guess though, it could be something totally different.

Comment: @ChristopherOicles is right. You read every line of the file to increment `counter` but you never reset the file pointer after reading every line. In addition you should close the `ifstream` once you're done using it.

Comment: @JonnyHenly So, I tried flushing it using the reference you gave me. Still not working. Trying to do a bunch of random self-projects for programming practice. It's awesome how much I've learned in a few weeks.

Comment: I hope this is just for experimentation and not to be used in any serious capacity because XOR encryption is super weak. I still see it in production code now and then.

Comment: @tadman It's just for personal testing, haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string content[10000];
string encryptedContent[10000];
```

This is wrong because it is creating 20000 strings (you probably think it is creating a large enough character array to read the data).

`string content;` is enough. It can be resized to handle any length of strings.

You just need to read/write the file in binary:

```
int main() 
{
    string input = "input.txt";
    ifstream file(input, ios::binary);
    if (!file.is_open())
    {
        cout << "\tUnable to open the file: " << input << "!\n";
        return 0;
    }

    string plaintext;

    //read the file    
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    size_t size = (size_t)file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0);
    plaintext.resize(size, 0);
    file.read(&plaintext[0], size);

    cout << "reading:\n" << plaintext << "\n";

    //encrypt the content
    string encrypted = encrypt(plaintext);

    //encrypt again so it goes back to original (for testing)
    string decrypted = encrypt(encrypted);

    cout << "testing:\n" << decrypted << "\n";

    /* Write encryption to file */
    ofstream outputFile("output.txt", ios::binary);
    outputFile.write(encrypted.data(), encrypted.size());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, this makes a lot of sense! Thanks, Barmak! :)